# ReplaceAll and complex numbers

Tags: replacement

I am currently trying to "canonicalize" my expressions with complex numbers. One thing I want to do is to replace expressions such as `x x*` (where * denotes complex conjugation) with `Abs[x]^2`.

My attempt at a solution was to write the following rule

```
z_ Conjugate[z_] :> Abs[z]^2
```

This works for some expressions, but unfortunately not for all, as the the following example demonstrates:

```
ReplaceAll[Times[x, Conjugate[x], Power[Plus[1, Times[-1, Times[x, Conjugate[x]]]], -1]], RuleDelayed[Times[Pattern[z, Blank[]], Conjugate[Pattern[z, Blank[]]]], Abs[Power[z, 2]]]]
(* Times[Power[Abs[x],2],Power[Plus[1,Times[-1,x,Conjugate[x]]],-1]] *)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You need to use [`ReplaceRepeated`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceRepeated.html) (`//.` for short) to do the replacement. The issue is that everything is inside the same `Times` head, and `ReplaceAll` will only do one replacement per expression.

Comment: @LukasLang Thank you. Now I understand.

Comment: Also, `z Conjugate[z] // 
  ComplexExpand[#, {z}, TargetFunctions -> {Abs, Arg}] & // Simplify`